# nsight EE and nvvp both crash during startup on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: crash, nvidia, nsight, nvvp

Whenenevr I start both applications they crash after the splash-screen appears. A small dialog appears with the message `an error has occurred. see the log file null` (I don't know where to find said null file).

**nsight console error message**

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
CompileCommand: exclude java/lang/reflect/Array.newInstance
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.<init>(Storage.java:97)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:84)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:75)
at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:563)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7e9a5fbe
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:337)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:281)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:197)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:191)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:52)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:59)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findAddURLMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:43)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.<clinit>(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:37)
... 14 more
```

**nvvp console error message**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.<init>(Storage.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @16022d9d
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:337)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:281)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:197)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findAddURLMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.<clinit>(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:37)
    ... 14 more
```

What's unusual is that nsight 7.5 (installed previously still works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Turns out that I was using Java 9 which eclipse (which nsight and nvvp are based on) does not yet support.

Changes made to my  `.bashrc` file

```
export J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```